# Control over font in WidgetKit .widgetLabel?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication, watchos-10

The top left WidgetKit Complication renders correctly, but when positioned in the bottom right, it's truncated.  How can I prevent that, do we have any control over the `Text` as far as font etc?

```
  .widgetLabel {
                                Gauge(value: Double(totalEnergyBurned ?? 0), in: 0...Double(highestEnergyBurnedInPastWeek ?? 0)) {
                                    Text("Not shown")
                                } currentValueLabel: {
                                    Text("Not shown")
                                } minimumValueLabel: {
                                    Text("\(0)")
                                } maximumValueLabel: {
                                    Text(formatEnergyToAbbreviation(number: highestEnergyBurnedInPastWeek))
                                        //FIXME: how do I prevent this from truncating?
                                    
                                }
```

[image]